# Не работает простая функция

Tags: php, switch

```
function cat($id) {
switch ($id) {
case '1': $cat = 'Скрипты'; $caturl = 'scripts'; break;
case '2': $cat = 'Программы'; $caturl = 'programms'; break;
case '3': $cat = 'Для телефона'; $caturl = 'mobile'; break;
case '4': $cat = 'Видео'; $caturl = 'video'; break;
case '5': $cat = 'Аудио'; $caturl = 'audio'; break;
case '6': $cat = 'Книги'; $caturl = 'books'; break;
case '7': $cat = 'Ключи'; $caturl = 'keys'; break;
case '8': $cat = 'Дизайн'; $caturl = 'design'; break;
case '9': $cat = 'Остальное'; $caturl = 'other'; break;
default: $cat = 'Ошибка категории'; $caturl = '';
}
}
cat('4');
echo $cat.' '.$caturl;
```

Должно вывести `Видео video`, однако выводит пустоту и говорит что переменные не найдены

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возвращаем из функции массив который разбиваем по переменным:

```
function cat($id) {
  switch ($id) {
    case '1': return array('Скрипты', 'scripts');
    case '2': return array('Программы', 'programms');
    case '3': return array('Для телефона', 'mobile');
    case '4': return array('Видео', 'video');
    case '5': return array('Аудио', 'audio');
    case '6': return array('Книги', 'books');
    case '7': return array('Ключи', 'keys');
    case '8': return array('Дизайн', 'design');
    case '9': return array('Остальное', 'other');
    default: return array('Ошибка категории', '');
  }
}

list($cat, $caturl) = cat('4');

echo $cat.' '.$caturl;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function cat($id) {
  $cats = array(
    '1'=>array('cat'=>'category 1', 'url'=>'cat1'),
    '2'=>array('cat'=>'category 2', 'url'=>'cat2')
  );
  return(isset($cats[$id]))? $cats[$id] : null;
}

if(!is_null($category = cat('1'))) {
  var_dump($category);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function cat($id) {
switch ($id) {
case '1': $cat = 'Скрипты'; $caturl = 'scripts'; break;
case '2': $cat = 'Программы'; $caturl = 'programms'; break;
case '3': $cat = 'Для телефона'; $caturl = 'mobile'; break;
case '4': $cat = 'Видео'; $caturl = 'video'; break;
case '5': $cat = 'Аудио'; $caturl = 'audio'; break;
case '6': $cat = 'Книги'; $caturl = 'books'; break;
case '7': $cat = 'Ключи'; $caturl = 'keys'; break;
case '8': $cat = 'Дизайн'; $caturl = 'design'; break;
case '9': $cat = 'Остальное'; $caturl = 'other'; break;
default: $cat = 'Ошибка категории'; $caturl = '';
}
return Array($cat, $caturl);
}
list($cat, $caturl) = cat('4');
```

Comment: нужно чтобы переменные $cat и $caturl выдавались отдельно для использования в разных местах

Comment: @Rufex почитайте учебник хоть какой-нибудь

Comment: @Rufex, функция всегда возвращает тольео **одно** значение